# Change the styles of a specific DIV in another DIV

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSS selector for first element with class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class)

Currently I have a code that looks something like this:

```
<div class="content">
   <div style="...">...</div>
   <div class="post">...</div>
   <div class="post">...</div>
   <div class="post">...</div>
   <div class="post">...</div>
   <div class="post">...</div>
</div>
```

How can I target the first "post" class in this example? In other words, what CSS selector do I have to use?

```
<div class="content">
   <div style="...">...</div>
   <div class="post">...</div> <--- I need a selector to edit the styles for this.
   <div class="post">...</div>
   <div class="post">...</div>
   <div class="post">...</div>
   <div class="post">...</div>
</div>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried .post:first-child ?

Comment: Neither `.post:first-child` nor `.post:first-of-type` will work. See my answer to the duplicate question. In your case, you need two rules: one for `.content .post`, and another for `.content .post ~ .post` to undo the styles for subsequent `.post` elements.

Answer (score 3):

You need the nth-child selector

```
.post:nth-child(2)
{
//css
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gXtG9/)

Comment: I tried that, and it did not work.